# NSSrring lost value

Tags: nsstring

I can`t figure out why my NSString lost its value in a IBAction.

I have in my .m the variable declaration :

@implementation myfile.m

NSString *text2=nil;

In (void)viewDidLoad I assign the value to text2 correctly, but when I fired the IBAction the debugger tells me the  and text2 has lost the value.

The IBAction routine is placed in the .m file.

Please, anyone can tell me what I doing wrong ?

Advanced thanks

Comment: can you put the exact code that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but just if anyone else stumbles upon it.

if you use ARC the nil value you assign basicly tells the compiler to dealloc when possible.

just do

```
 @implementation myfile.m {

      NSString *stringName;

 }

 - (void)viewDidLoad {

      stringName = @"some-value";
 }
```